# Finiteness of moments

Tags: normal-distribution

Please can you explain the meaning of this text in *italics*, specifically what is the α being referred to here, in layman terms.

**Finiteness of Moments and Higher Order Effects.**

For thick tailed distributions, *moments higher than α are not “finite”*, i.e., they cannot be computed. They can certainly be measured in finite samples –thus giving
the illusion of finiteness. But they typically show a great degree of instability.

Answer (score 1):

They are talking about things like $\mathbb E X^k$ or $\mathbb E |X|^k$ for values of $k>\alpha$.  *Higher moments* means expectation of higher powers. The point the author is trying to make is that, for instance, $E X^2$ might exist but $E X^3$ might not.

Comment: Thank you for your help!